# how to create css 'nav' with default selected element

Tags: css, html, nav

I am new to web development and I am using nav to hold serval links, question is when the page been displayed I want one fo the element in nav been selected, is there attribute of nav I can use? If no way to do that, is it possible to achieve this by using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You would usually have a CSS class for the selected item. For instance in bootstrap, the `active` class makes the nav item appear selected: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/

To navigate to a particular link, you can use javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myLink').click();
```

or

```
window.location = 'http://myurl';
```

Comment: I actually want the nav item been selected, not just looks like selected, is that possible? As every nav item has a link, so select means go to that link.